# Linux Free Disk Space per Device

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization, shell-scripting, unix-shell

In my system, `df -hT` outputs something like this:

```
> df -hT 
Sist. Arq.     Tipo      Tam. Usado Disp. Uso% Montado em
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  1,9G  8,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,9G  616K  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,9G  1,8M  1,9G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /.snapshots
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/pgsql
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/opt
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/libvirt/images
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/mailman
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/machines
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/crash
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/mariadb
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/lib/named
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /usr/local
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/spool
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /opt
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/cache
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /srv
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/log
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /var/tmp
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27% /tmp
/dev/sda8      vfat      340G  313G   27G  93% /mnt/Data
/dev/sda7      xfs       200G  143G   58G  72% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs     385M   44K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      fuseblk   287G  190G   98G  67% /run/media/jaques/OS
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat      7,5G  2,1G  5,4G  28% /run/media/jaques/9843-A435
```

but I'd like to have each device listed only once, regardless how many times it gets mounted.

I'd like to have something simpler, like this:

```
> df -hT 
Sist. Arq.     Tipo      Tam. Usado Disp. Uso%
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27%
/dev/sda8      vfat      340G  313G   27G  93%
/dev/sda7      xfs       200G  143G   58G  72%
/dev/sda3      fuseblk   287G  190G   98G  67%
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat      7,5G  2,1G  5,4G  28%
```

Is it possible? How?

System information, if needed:

```
OpenSuse Tumbleweed
Kernel 4.10.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is easier to edit the output of `df` (for instance with `awk`) than to try to tweak its options. So what I would do is to define an alias

```
alias my_df="df -hT|awk -F% '$1!=p&&$1!~/tmpfs/{print $1 FS;p=$1}'"
```

and use it whenever you want the reduced output. With the input you provided

```
$ my_df
Sist. Arq.     Tipo      Tam. Usado Disp. Uso%
/dev/sda6      btrfs      80G   22G   58G  27%
/dev/sda8      vfat      340G  313G   27G  93%
/dev/sda7      xfs       200G  143G   58G  72%
/dev/sda3      fuseblk   287G  190G   98G  67%
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat      7,5G  2,1G  5,4G  28%
```

**Explanation:**
The output of `df` is piped through `awk` which, as instructed by `-F%`, splits each input line into two parts, `$1` to be dealt with and `$2` to be discarded. Then, if `$1` is different from `p` (see below) and `$1` does not match `tmpfs`, we print it with a final `%`. Finally, we assign the value of `$1` to `p` so that, if the next line is the same as this one, we don’t print it.

Hope all is clear.

Comment: Thanks @Dario. I though I would have to rely on something like that but you gave me the complete solution saving my little brain from thinking!